# If the sum of two series converges uniformly, do the two series converge uniformly?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let's say $S_n(x)$ is a series that converges uniformly.
and $S_n(x) = S'_n(x) + S''_n(x)$
Do the series $S'_n(x)$ and $S''_n(x)$ converge uniformly too?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Obviously not in general: take any series $S'(x)$  and set $S''(x)=-S'(x)$.

Comment: i just read it, thanks alot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't have to converge at all.  Let $S'_n(x)=-n, S''_n(x)=n$, then $S_n(x)=0$ converges very nicely.

Answer (score 1):

No. Take $S_n(x)=0$ ($x\in\mathbb R$), $S_n'(x)=x/n$, and $S_n''(x)=-x/n$. Then neither $S_n'$ nor $S_n''$ converge uniformly (although they both converge).